# HTML in Order Printer templates of Shopify

Tags: shopify

I am passing some HTML in one of the fields to enhance my order formatting in the Order Printer. There is a problem however. HTML tags aren rendered properly. It looks like that when its rendering  tag with HTML intities so < becomes &lt ; for example.

What's the best way to get it to render HTML in fields? Is there something like an unescape filter?

Comment: HTML is escaped only in a richtext fields. If you are using a richtext field swap it for a html or textarea field instead.

Comment: Ah thanks for that. I managed to resolve this using encodeURI on the frontend and using decodeURI filter inside the order template.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is interested I resolved it by URI encoding the string using JS encodeURI before it's sent to Shopify. Then used "decodeURI" filter in the order template